# Whyonly my drawLine function working properly?

Tags: javascript, html

so I'm at the beginning of learning canvas and how to control it, and in my code the only function that's not drawing anything on the surface of the canvas is drawLine, which is supposed to draw a dot or line if it's triggered by onMove.
Could you please help me understand why?

The canvas service

```
'use strict'

let gPencil = { pos: null, isDown: false }
let gShape = ''
let gColor = ''
let gStrokeColor = ''
let gDrawings = []

function addListeners() {
    addMouseListeners()
    addTouchListeners()
    window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
        resizeCanvas()
    })
}       

function addMouseListeners() {
    gElCanvas.addEventListener('mousedown', onDown)
    gElCanvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onMove)
    gElCanvas.addEventListener('mouseup', onUp)
}

function addTouchListeners() {
    gElCanvas.addEventListener('touchstart', onDown)
    gElCanvas.addEventListener('touchmove', onMove)
    gElCanvas.addEventListener('touchend', onUp)
}

function drawShape(x, y) {
    gCtx.moveTo(x, y)
    gCtx.beginPath()

    if (gShape === '') {
        alert('You have not chosen a shape.')
        return
    }
    else if (gShape === 'squares') drawRect(x, y)
    else if (gShape === 'triangles') drawTriangle(x, y)
    else if(gShape === 'circles') drawCircle(x, y)
    else if (gShape === 'pencil') drawLine(x, y)

    gDrawings.push(gPencil.pos)
    gCtx.save()
}

function drawRect(x, y) {
    gCtx.strokeRect(x, y, 40, 40)
    gCtx.fillRect(x, y, 40, 40)
    gCtx.stroke()
}

function drawTriangle(x, y) {
    gCtx.lineTo(x + 70, y)
    gCtx.lineTo(x, y + 70)
    gCtx.closePath()
    gCtx.stroke()
    gCtx.fill()
}

function drawCircle(x, y) {
    gCtx.arc(x, y, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI)
    gCtx.stroke()
    gCtx.fill()
}

function drawLine(x, y) {
    gCtx.lineTo(x ,y)
    gCtx.stroke()
    gCtx.fill()
}

function resizeCanvas() {
    const elContainer = document.querySelector('.canvas-container')
    gElCanvas.width = elContainer.clientWidth
}

function onDrawLine(ev) {
    if (!gPen.isDown) return
    const { offsetX, offsetY } = ev

    gPen.pos = { x: offsetX, y: offsetY }
    gLine.push(gPen.pos)
    
    gCtx.lineTo(offsetX, offsetY)
    gCtx.stroke()
}
```

The canvas controller

```
'use strict'

let gElCanvas
let gCtx

function onInit() {
    gElCanvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
    gCtx = gElCanvas.getContext('2d')
    gCtx.lineWidth = 4
    addListeners()
}

function onDown(ev) {
    ev.stopPropagation()
    const elNav = document.querySelector('.nav-bar')
    gShape = elNav.querySelector('.shapes').value
    gStrokeColor = elNav.querySelector('#stroke-color').value
    gColor = elNav.querySelector('#color').value
    gCtx.fillStyle = gColor
    gCtx.strokeStyle = gStrokeColor
    gDrawings = []

    gPencil.isDown = true

    const x = ev.offsetX
    const y = ev.offsetY

    gPencil.pos = {x, y}

    // gCtx.beginPath()
    // gCtx.moveTo(x, y)
    drawShape(x, y)
}

function onMove(ev) {
    
    ev.stopPropagation()
    if (!gPencil.isDown) return

    const { offsetX: x, offsetY: y } = ev
    gPencil.pos = { x, y }
    // gShape = document.querySelector('.nav-bar .shapes').value
    drawShape(x, y)
    gDrawings.push(gPencil.pos)
}

function onClearBtn() {
    gCtx.clearRect(0, 0, gElCanvas.width, gElCanvas.height)
}

function onUp(ev) {
    ev.stopPropagation()
    gCtx.closePath()
    gPencil.isDown = false
}

function onDownloadCanvas(elA) {
    const canvasContent = gElCanvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg')
    elA.href = canvasContent
}

function onImgInput(ev) {
    loadImageFromInput(ev, renderImg)
}

function loadImageFromInput(ev, onImageReady) {
    const reader = new FileReader()

    reader.onload = ev => {
        let img = new Image()
        img.src = ev.target.result
        img.onload = () => onImageReady(img)
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(ev.target.files[0])
}

function renderImg(img) {
    gElCanvas.height = (img.naturalHeight / img.naturalWidth) * gElCanvas.width
    gCtx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, gElCanvas.width, gElCanvas.height)
}


function onSaveBtn() {
    gCtx.save()
}

function coverCanvasWithImg(elImg) {
    gElCanvas.height = (elImg.naturalHeight / elImg.naturalWidth) * gElCanvas.width
    gCtx.drawImage(elImg, 0, 0, gElCanvas.width, gElCanvas.height)
}

function onShareImg() {
  
    const imgDataUrl = gElCanvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg') 

    function onSuccess(uploadedImgUrl) {
        const url = encodeURIComponent(uploadedImgUrl)
        window.open(`https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=${url}&t=${url}`)
    }
    
    doUploadImg(imgDataUrl, onSuccess)
}

function doUploadImg(imgDataUrl, onSuccess) {
    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('img', imgDataUrl)

    const XHR = new XMLHttpRequest()
    XHR.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if (XHR.readyState !== XMLHttpRequest.DONE) return
        if (XHR.status !== 200) return console.error('Error uploading image')
        const { responseText: url } = XHR
        console.log('Got back live url:', url)
        onSuccess(url)
    }
    XHR.onerror = (req, ev) => {
        console.error('Error connecting to server with request:', req, '\nGot response data:', ev)
    }
    XHR.open('POST', '//ca-upload.com/here/upload.php')
    XHR.send(formData)
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Canvas Exercise</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body onload="onInit()">
    <header>
        <h1>Mister Canvas</h1>
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav-bar">
                <li><input type="color" id="stroke-color" value="#ffffff"></li>
                <li><input type="color" id="color" value="#ffffff"></li>
                <li><select class="shapes">
                    <option value="">Select a shape</option>
                    <option value="squares">Square</option>
                    <option value="circles">Circle</option>
                    <option value="triangles">Triangle</option>
                    <option value="pencil">Pencil</option>
                </select></li>
                <li><button class="nav-bar-btn" onclick="onSaveBtn()">Save</button></li>
                <li><button class="nav-bar-btn" onclick="onClearBtn()">Clean</button></li>
                <li><input type="file" onchange="onImgInput(event)" accept="image/*"></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="download-btn" onclick="onDownloadCanvas(this)" download="my-canvas.jpg">Download</a></li>
                <li><button class="share-btn" onclick="onShareImg()"> Share to Facebook </button></li>
                
            </ul>
        </nav>

    </header>
    <main>
        <div class="canvas-container">
            <canvas width="450" height="450"></canvas>
        </div>
    </main>
    <script src="js/canvas-controller.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services/canvas.service.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried to debugg it and read a few times all the lines in each js file,
asked the chatGPT and one more dev community , but got no answer.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I would try injecting the following code in the drawLine() function and comment the other lines withing the fucntion:

```
gCtx.beginPath();
gCtx.moveTo(0, 0);
gCtx.lineTo(100, 200);
gCtx.stroke();
```

I would check if the above code works, and then I would change 100, 200 with x, y. If this fails, check with console.log the values of x and y. If it executes nicely, try removing the moveTo line and check again.